# Java: 2D List into CSV

Tags: java, csv

I have a **2D Listoflist** in **Java**

```
List<List<String>> listOflists
```

which is list of say 3 lists:

```
List1 = {10,20,30,40}

List2 = {Accouting, Research, Sales, Operations}

List3 = {122,123,124,125}
```

I would like to convert it to CSV file sepererated by "," but each list corresponding to one column as below:

```
10,Accounting,122
20,Research,124
30,Sales,123
40,Operations,167
```

in fact I am going use this csv file later to write into mysql.

Right now I use HSSFWorkbook(), then make it as excel, then convert excel into csv and then export it to mysql, and finally delete both excel and csv. which I think is not efficeint.

so how can I convert that `List<List<String>>` into "," seperated CSV file?

Thank you

Comment: Your inner list type is `String`, but the examples you give are not.

Comment: I don't think It deserve -1 just because your doubt, yes I am using `List<List<String>>` and it works. you imaging all those numbers are also string :( that's it.

Comment: I wasn't the one -1 you. I just commented.

Comment: Oh, OK, thanks anyway for your comment. I really wish when people do -1, also explain why -1 so if the questioner can correct oneself.

Comment: You might want to read through https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180. The format is quite simple, but there are some edge cases you should code for. Quotes and commas in strings, jagged lists, linux line endings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

// setup the header line
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("your,header,line,stuff");
sb.append(lineSeparator);

// now append your data in a loop
for (i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    sb.append(list1.get(i));
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append(list2.get(i));
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append(list3.get(i));
    sb.append(lineSeparator);
}

// now write to file
Files.write(Paths.get("path/to/where/you/want/output.csv"), sb.toString().getBytes());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int innerListSize = listOfLists.get(0).size();

for (i = 0; i < innerListSize; i++) {
    for (List<String> innerList : listOfLists) {
        Files.write(innerList.get(i) + ",");
    }
    Files.write('\n');
}
```

Note that you will have a comma at the end of each line. It can be removed by changing the optimized for loop to make use of iterator, and not write comma to file when iterator.hasNext() is false.